# SP execution from BizTalk dynamic send port

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a sp which I am executing from BizTalk orchestration.

When I am executing the SP in SQL server it's taking 10 sec, but when I am executing it from orchestration using below code, it's taking 1 hour.

```
  sqlStoredProcRequestXml = reportRequestXml;

  sqlStoredProcRequestXml(WCF.Action)= sqlProcedureName;
  sqlStoredProcRequestXml(WCF.BindingType)="sqlBinding";
  sqlStoredProcRequestXml(WCF.EnableTransaction) = false;

  sqlStoredProcRequestXml(WCF.BindingConfiguration)= @"<binding name=""sqlBinding"" sendTimeout=""02:30:00"" />";
```

SndRcvSqlStoreProcRequestResponsePort(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.Address)="mssql://" + dbServer + "//" + dbDatabase;
SndRcvSqlStoreProcRequestResponsePort(Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.TransportType)="WCF-SQL";

Can anyone explain why there is 1 hour diff in execution of the SP.

Comment: Did you check where exactly the time is spent in yr whole process, is it on just executing the sp or the entire orch.

Comment: It's on just executing the sp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing specific to BizTalk delaying the sp call so much. You can try following to find the root cause:

1. Use SQL profiler to see the actual execution time of SP via BizTalk
2. Check for other delays in your environment, such as SQL performance, msgbox db, BizTalk host throttling
3. Check event viewer log for any warning or error on send port host
4. Make sure you use same data and environment to test the SP outside BizTalk to compare result, sometime depending on size of data, yr query can run for long time in diff env.
5. You can also take DBAs help to sql profile your sp call

Answer (score 0):

This don't explain such difference (1 hour vs 10 sec is a lot), but when you invoke from an Orchestration:

1. Your message first go to the Message Box
2. The message is catched by the Send Port
3. Send Port invokes the SP
4. The response then goes to the Message Box
5. The Orchestration gets the response message form Message Box

You aren't calling directly to your SP from the Orchestration, the message travels through BizTalk, but this don't explain so big difference, unless you have problems on your MsgBox.